# Made a app and want to access its models in other apps and want to restrict user registration for accessing website

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-apps

I am working on a django project , I am a beginner and thought that i should make a new app for user management so made it but now want to access the models of that app from other apps and also want to ensure that before accessing evry url of website the user has to login i have used UserCreatonForm and extended it.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to StackOverflow. It would be very helpful for the people here if you elaborated a bit more on what exactly you're trying to do, and what you have tried so far. Could you maybe edit your question and add some code?

Answer (score 0):

To access the models of this app in other apps just use import. For example if a model is called Dev in an app called people, just go to the app in which you want to import, and type:

```
from people.models import Dev
```

Then you can use this model any way you like. Also, to make sure that only logged-in users have access to your views, use the login_required decorator. Let's say I have a view called users_list, to apply login_required decorator to it, I have to do the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
```

After you've imported the decorator, just use it before your view, like this:

```
@login_required()
def users_list(request):
...
```

Now, this decorator will force users to log in before they access the view.

Comment: Can something be done as i will use only one login decorator and it would appy to all the functions or views

Comment: Unfortunately, I think there isn't one simple way to universally apply login_decorators, I think there are some modules that might enable that but they'll add complexity rather than simplicity. Fortunately though, there is a very finite amount of views you'll end up having in your app, so just copy paste it a few times.